# Selecting the child of a block in a plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a plugin right now and can't get it to work.

I want to make a container like [**this one**](https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/?ref_type=sitefooter)

If you click on a block, the cover should move into a specific direction.
But every time I want to get the child of the `.coverFrame-Container`, it just gives me the link of the file + `' > .cover'`

Here is my code:

```
$.fn.coverBlock = function () {
    // Settings
    var settings = $.extend({
        direction: 'up',
        speed: 400
    });

    $(this).click(function () {
        element = this;
        console.log(this + ' .cover');
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('.coverFrame').coverBlock();
});
```

This is just in debug now.

The console-log in the click-function just gives me this:

```
file:///G:/wamp/www/training/index.html# .cover
```

Without the addition +`' .cover'` it gives me the following:

```
<a href="#" class="coverFrame" style="display: block; height: 100px; width: 100px;">...</a>
```

How can I fix it that I can select the child and work with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using $(this) within the click function.